# dimension and rank misunderstood

Tags: linear-algebra

I read the following lemma :

If $A$ is the matrix of the coefficients with size $m \times n,\,$ then the dimension of solutions of this homogenous system has dimension $n-\operatorname{rank}(A).$

What does "the dimension of solutions " mean?

Can you give an easy example?

Comment: The "dimension of solutions" is the maximal number of linearly independent solution vectors.

Comment: Indipendant solutions vectors are the solutions of the matrix (x_1,x_2........,x_n)?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I understood everything thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a homogeneous system of equations $Ax = 0$ has always the solution $x=0.$ but it may also have many other solutions. for examplle if you look at $x + y + z= 0$ 
then this system of one equation in three variable has infinitely many solutions. here are some:

$x = -1, y = 1, z = 0: x = -1, y = 0, z = 1$

you can think of many others. in fact $x = -t - s, y = t, z = s$ is always a solution for any values of $s, t$ because they all add up to zero. here you see that this is two fold infinitely many solutions. the number $2$ is called the dimension of the solutions of the homogeneous system of equation $Ax = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Write the homogeneous system on its matrix form

$$Ax=0$$
hence a solution $x$ is a vector in the kernel of $A$ (or of the linear transformation $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m,\; x\mapsto Ax$) which its dimension by the rank-nullity theorem is $n-\operatorname{rk}(A)$ where $n$ is the dimension of  $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: do you think you start learning algebra with the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Well I just know that the rank is the maximum number linear indipendant vectors.And it is hard to connect it with the number of solutions

Comment: Also why the fundamental system of solutions has n-r or n-rk(A) solutions aren't they supposed to be the length of the matrix m?

Comment: an example $3x_1-x_2+x_3=0 $then a tripplet solves the problem $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$

Answer (score 0):

It refers to $\dim\{x\in R^n:A x=0\}$ (It's easy to see that such a set is a subspace).

Comment: So they mean that if we have rk(A)=the number of lineary indipendant vectors and we do n-rk(A) and in our solution which will be in the form for example $(x_1,x_2. ....)$ we will have exactly n-rk(A) parameters for example if $n-rk(A)=2$ our solutions might be $(p,q,p-q,pq)$ for example?

Comment: Yes but i don't like much the part where you say "will have exactly n-rk(A)" parameters, I'm gonna elaborate now. Edit: I won't cause Sami already said what I was gonna say.